# Freestanding network connection GUI application

Tags: networking, gui

Does anyone know of a freestanding desktop independent GUI application for connecting to a (wireless) network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by André, use *wicd*. To start it as a regular GUI application, use the command `wicd-client --no-tray`. To use a wireless connection you also need to specify the interface, e.g. `wlan0`, in Preferences -> General Settings -> Wireless interface.

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) is the one used in Ubuntu but can theoretically be installed on basically any Linux. An alternative would be [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Isn't NetworkManager some kind of desktop applet? How do I bring up its GUI in a window manager like Blackbox say?

Comment: No, the NetworkManager applet is a seperat package that uses network manager (called `nm-applet`). The network manager should have an interface you can run by itself. Try running `nm-connection-editor`

Comment: OK, I see. But there seems to be no way to start using a connection in the connection editor or am I wrong?

Comment: Seems you are right, never noticed that. Try wicd, I used it a few years ago and it worked fine for me. I think you have to uninstall NetworkManager to avoid conflicts but I don't really remember ;-)